# MediaBundle + CKEditor : Youtube video are not working

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-cmf, sonata-media-bundle

Hello i'am trying to use SonataBundle and CKEditor in a CMF project.
I am not able to get the video in pages. Probably it is a problem of ckeditor when it generate the HTML. I want to know if i need to install a specific plugin to load sonata youtube media to get them working in pages.

Comment: Asking a full tutorial is not a good practice on stack overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with more information (what you tried, error you get ...)

Comment: i did not ask for tutorial. thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you are not asking for a tutorial could you update your post as suggested by @n3k? Because the statement "_i did not found a good tutorial_" it's really strange don't you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to load a youtube video into your CMS and then try to load it into CKEditor. That's only useful if you want to attach the video to content within the CMS.

To add the ability to CKEditor to link youtube videos simply [search for a plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addons/contents?sort_by=field_custom_downloads_value&sort_order=DESC&page=0) that supports the providers for video's you want to add. A very powerful plugin is [Media (oEmbed) Plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/oembed). But you might want something simpler, that is up to you.

**Adding plugins to CKEditor in Sonata**

1. You can add the plugin to sonata's CKEditor base bundle by following the [IvoryCKEditorBundle documentation for adding plugins](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/plugin.html).
2. (Less preferred) Replace the CKEdtior base bundle with your own bundle, which [you can build here](http://ckeditor.com/builder). You do so by making sure none of the sonata CKEditor css/js is loaded, and instead load your own. Which can be done on several ways but one is [explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/version.html).